# How to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH in CMakeLists?

Tags: linux, cmake

On my workstation, I have to load module to increment the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (`module load arpack`). It seems that *cmake* can only access this variable by using `$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`. But when printing this variable I get a list of directories seperated by `:` and I believe *cmake* does not understand it as a list of directories to find libraries, as a consequence, the following does not work:

```
find_library (Arpack_LIBRARY libarpack.a PATH $ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH})
```

and

```
message(STATUS $ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH})
```

prints

```
/home/user:/home/user/lib:/usr/lib:/lib
```

This is how I want to find my library. How can I transform `$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}` to an exploitable list of directories ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CMake a list is just a string with semicolon-separated parts. For make *colon*-separated string to be *semicolon*-separated, use [string(REPLACE)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/string.html#replace) command:

```
string(REPLACE ":" ";" LIBRARY_DIRS $ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH})
```

Resulted variable can be used in `find_library` call:

```
find_library (Arpack_LIBRARY libarpack.a PATHS ${LIBRARY_DIRS})
```